# The sqlite database to the apache superset, but while trying the absolute path of the .db file, I'm getting error message

Tags: database, sqlite, putty, apache-superset

I've to add the sqlite database to the apache superset, but while trying the absolute path of the .db file,
I'm getting error message.How can I fix this issue?
I've also tried to add these sqlite alchemy paths, I'm facing the same issue:

i. `sqlite:////home/opc/boq_db.db?check_same_thread=false`

ii. `sqlite:///C:/home/opc/boq_db.db`
but while using this one

iii. `sqlite:///home\opc\boq_db.db`
there's a success in test connection, but while trying to create the dataset, I'm getting the main file where the data is empty. while checking in the putty, what I found that there's data inside the file. then why it's showing empty?